# Why is /ENTRY linker option not required?

Tags: visual-c++, linker, msvcrt

I noted that in the default linker settings for a VC++ console project the "entry point" is left empty. Using dumpbin on the generated executable I saw

```
entry point (004110FF) @ILT+250(_mainCRTStartup)
```

I also checked the command line option of the project properties and there is no "/ENTRY" linker option given.

So how does the linker determine the entry point of the generated executable? I can think of 2 options:

1) there is some "#pragma comment(linker, "/enty:_mainCRTStartup") burried in the CRT
      source code. But I didn't find it.

2) the linker itself derives this information from the "/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE" option.
      So the option in Visual Studio will just **overwrite** the choice made by link.exe

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Sorry, found the answer myself. Just sharing what I found:

My 2nd guess was correct. The linker itself derives this information from other settings given (e.g. /subsystem:console). See MSDN [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f9t8842e(v=VS.100).aspx)

So the option in the project properties is needed only when you want to provide an entry point other than _mainCRTStartup.

Comment: You should add your comment as an answer to your own question, and then accept it when the system allows you to do so.

Answer (score 0):

The 2nd guess was correct. The linker itself derives this information from other settings given (e.g. /subsystem:console). See [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f9t8842e%28v=VS.71%29.aspx). So the option in the project properties is needed only when you want to provide an entry point other than _mainCRTStartup.